# How to clear history in Byobu?

Tags: byobu

I've been trying to clear the history of a window in Byobu but I haven't been successful. Neither `reset` nor `clear` actually clear the history, you can still see it when you enter in scrollback mode.

I'm guessing I should use tmux's `clear-history` command, but I don't know how to use that command from within Byobu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using screen keybindings, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>,
then <kbd>:</kbd> (colon), to get a `:` prompt, where you can enter the `clear-history` command.

Comment: And if not using screen keybindings, you can find the escape sequence in the byobu configuration menu (F9). For me, it was Ctrl-b instead.

Answer (score 3):

From your terminal, run

```
byobu clear-history
```

For a one-liner, you can run this or save it as a bash alias:

```
clear && byobu clear-history
```

Comment: Are you sure that this works?

Comment: I tested it, and it cleared my scrollback history although it did not clear my current screen.

Comment: Thanks. The reason I was asking is that I couldn't find this mentioned in `byobu -h`.